# How to use selector name as a variable in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, datatables

I am struggling to use an input name value as a selector to run a variable.
At the present moment I have 3 datatables with 1 search button each to update the table.

I am finding this code repetitive as for each new table I add, I must also add a new click function like so:

```
    //example table and button
<button id="test1button" type="button" name="test1" class="tables">Submit</button>

<table id="test1">

</table>


//the codes I am trying to run
            var test1 = $('#test1').DataTable({});

            var test2 = $('#test2').DataTable({});

            var test3 = $('#test3').DataTable({});

            $('#test1button').click( function() {
                 test1.ajax.reload();
            });

            $('#test2button').click( function() {
                 test2.ajax.reload();
            });

            $('#test3button').click( function() {
                 test3.ajax.reload();
            });
```

So I thought it might be eaiser and shorter to find a way to combine the code add a name to the button as use that as a value to determine which var = test* to run.
So I tried this:

```
        $('.tables').click( function() {
            var getdatatable = this.name; //e.g. value=test1
            getdatatable.ajax.reload();
        });
```

This correctly retrieves the name of the var that needs to be ran e.g. test1, but when I try use that value to run the vars it doesn't work.

This works

```
    $('.tables').click( function() {
        test1.ajax.reload();
    });
```

but this doesn't

```
    $('.tables').click( function() {
        var getdatatable = this.name; //e.g. value=test1
        getdatatable.ajax.reload();
    });
```

Can I not use an input name not be used in this way?

Comment: Is this.ajax.reload() not working? and one more thing test1 is id of data table or name?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
$('.tables').click( function() {
    var tableId= this.id;
    var getdatatable = $('#'+tableId).DataTable({});
    getdatatable.ajax.reload();
});
```

Comment: Yes this is simliar to other threads where I have researched where they use the id as a selector. But this wouldn't work in my situation because the reason all the datatables are seperated is because they all have different requirements and settings so I could't run it like that. Ideally I was wanting to know how make jquery believe an treat "this.name" value as an actual name of a variable

Comment: Or just `$('#'+this.id).DataTable({}).ajax.reload();`,  but couldn't you also pass the element you already have, `$(this).ajax.reload()`?  https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-elements-when-i-already-have-a-dom-element/

Comment: @DanFarrell here this returns element object, so it might return html table object but not DataTable.

Comment: Not sure if it can be used like that. Here is a link to datatables and you'll see they define all new tables in a new variable on it's own. And any futher calls to that datatable is called by using it's variable name. https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: @Rajashekhar that's right $(this) would only return the html and not datatables. So am I getting the right hint that there is no way to make jquery treat "this.name" as the name of a variable? This would be an easy solution as I've tested it by manually typing the var name in and it works.

Comment: Uhhh ok guys I think I found an option that actually make jquery treat "this.name" a name of a variable. eval(this.name) does the trick and tells jquery to treat it as the name of a variable. But my question is, is this safe to use?

Comment: Ok closing this question as marked because from reading datatables you can select the table and datatables will either try create a new table or if already done bring you back the old instance. So by editing some of your example above I got it to work

Comment: I think you missed my point, @adamgouldie, probably because I mistakenly left the DataTable call out.  `this` can already be passed to `$()`, making the invocation `$(this).DataTable({}).ajax.reload()`, which should work without using  some arbitrary naming convention for the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok closing this question as marked because from reading datatables you can select the table and datatables will either try create a new table or if already done bring you back the old instance. So by editing some of your example above I got it to work by using this.name as the selector instead